# Best strategy to build Classifier for Mixed Data with class imbalance

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, data-science

** Platform: R**

---

**Edit to Chris: I tried oversampling using variants of SMOTE. Also undersampling the majority (but the bad idea as only has 1800 rows anyways). Best sensitivity only 55 till now.**

---

*New ideas: Can I look at changing probability thresholds for rf classifier to get a higher Sensitivity or is that a wrong way to go about this ?*

---

I have a dataset which contains: 94 numeric features + 56 categorical features

I am trying to build a classifier to predict Target (disease/healthy).

2. Rows: 1812
3. Class imbalance ( Majority class(healthy : 1200))

Strategies I tried :

I tried SMOTE on training data( 80/20 split).

As a number of features are 150. 
I wanted to use feature selection. 
Filter methods (fs) don't work so well on mixed. So I used the Wrapper fs algorithm( recursive feature elimination) on the full feature set. Used random forest for rfe().

I got a subset of 23 features from rfe (all numeric). Wonder if rfe works with factor variables? or should I use dummy encoding first and then rfe?
I even tried hybrid feature selection alg. like the Genetic algorithm but sensitivity is very low after randomforest (50 % for disease class)

I am trying to achieve a high sensitivity. I am concentrating on the random forest as of now as my base classifier as it works well with the mixed datatype.
Issues: my best Cross validated accuracy is 70. Sensitivity : 50 . How can i improve sensitivity for disease class?

Feature selection for mixed data? 
I also tried PCA and FAMD for dimensionality reduction, but PC1 explains only 8 % variance. So that's out of the way.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi @LukeSkywalker!  Could you narrow down the question a little – at least to whether we're talking about R or python – an answer that covers both well would be long!  That said, have you tried the basics (up/down sampling, and class weights)?  Also, what metric are you optimising for?